# Trying to echo out custom field inside shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

I have this shortcode code currently -

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('latest_tweet')) {

function latest_tweet($atts, $content = null) {

    $args = array(
        "latest_tweet_icon_color"             => "#dddddd",
        "latest_tweet_icon_size"              => "70",
        "text_align"                          => "",
        "el_class"                            => ""
    );

    extract(shortcode_atts($args, $atts));

    global $my_theme;

    $html = "";

    $html .="<div class='latest-tweet-container $el_class' style='text-align:$text_align;'>";

    $html .= "<i class='ion-social-twitter-outline' style='color: $latest_tweet_icon_color; font-size: ${latest_tweet_icon_size}px;'></i>";
    $html .= "<div id='latest-tweet'></div>"; 

    echo '' . $my_theme['social-twitter'];

    $html .= "</div>";        

    return $html;
}

}

add_shortcode('latest_tweet', 'latest_tweet');
```

Now the array (icon color, size, align etc..) is pulling fields from a Visual Composer element, and the echo statement is pulling (social-twitter) from a theme options field. I can get echo to work, but it is being output outside of the div? How can I include it inside the latest-tweet-container div?

I have tried -

```
$html . = echo '' . $my_theme['social-twitter'];
```

But this just throws an error?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$html . = echo '' . $my_theme['social-twitter'];` will throw the error. because syntax is wrong.  you will try this:

```
$html.= ' ' . $my_theme['social-twitter'];
```